# ¿Cómo parar el ciclo en el momento deseado?

Tags: javascript, loops

El problema de mi ciclo Fibonacci, es que no sé cómo pararlo con el parámetro max, ya que actualmente max está funcionando como "max numeros de fibonacci", pero yo quiero que cuando el número de Fibonacci sea igual o mayor a max, el ciclo pare, lo haría con `break` pero entonces, ¿qué debería colocar en el `q<max`?;

```js
function p(max) {
  var fibonacci = [];
  fibonacci[0] = 0;
  fibonacci[1] = 1;
  var q = 2;

  for (; q < max; q++) {
    if (max > fibonacci[q])
      fibonacci[q] = fibonacci[q - 1] + fibonacci[q - 2];
    else break; // INTENTO CON BREAK <--
  }
  return fibonacci;
}

console.log(p(89));
```

Comment: este tipos de funciones debes hacerla recursivas, por favor agrega la funcion completa

Comment: Vaya, pensé que la habia editado.. Ya está editada

Comment: ponle un return en lugar del break y listo

Comment: Tampoco sirve con return..

Comment: El uso de `break` siempre me ha parecido inadecuado, lo veo como un _goto encubierto_. Siempre que lo veo, me chirría. Por ejemplo, en este caso lo primero que me preguntaría es ¿por qué un bucle `for` con un `break`? La estructura que se muestra es básicamente un bucle `for` simulando un bucle `while`, ¿por qué no usar un `while` directamente que sería más legible y no rompería el _flujo natural_ del programa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El `break` esta funcionando bien lo que pasa es que se ingresa al `else` en la primera instancia y detiene el ciclo sin llegar al max.

Esto ocurre porque estas comparando `fibonacci[2]` y ese valor no existe, la comparación se convierte en `undefined > 89 = false`. Para solucionar esto debes obtener el siguiente numero de la serie antes comparar, quedando de esta manera:

```js
function p(max){
var fibonacci = []; fibonacci[0] = 0; fibonacci[1] = 1; var q = 2;
 
 for(;q<max;q++){
   var next = fibonacci[q-1] + fibonacci[q-2];
   if(max > next) {
     fibonacci[q] = next;
   }
   else break; // INTENTO CON BREAK <--
 }
 return fibonacci;
  }
  
console.log(p(143));
```

Answer (score 4):

No tienes que cambiar nada, simplemente tienes que romper el ciclo por medio del [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/break) cuando no se cumpla la condición que comentas.

Cuando el `break` se ejecute, el bucle terminará sin comprobar la condición `if`.

```js
function p(max){
  var fibonacci = []; fibonacci[0] = 0; fibonacci[1] = 1; var q = 2;
  for(;q<max;q++){
    fibonacci[q] = fibonacci[q-1] + fibonacci[q-2];
      if(fibonacci[q] >= max) break;
  }
  return fibonacci;
}

console.log(p(89));
```

Comment: Si explicaras que hace el `break` dentro de un ciclo, tu respuesta estaria completa.

Comment: Eso ya lo hice y no me funcionaba, me devuelve [0,1]

Answer (score 2):

Como te ponía en un comentario, el único motivo por el que tienes que usar un `break` es porque estás usando un bucle `for` para algo que sería más sencillo y (en mi opinión) natural usar un bucle `while`.

Por ejemplo, si cambias el `for` a un `while` con la condición que quieres `q<max` (y moviendo opcionalmente el `if` interno a la condición del `while`), el código se simplifica considerablemente y ya no hace falta el `if...else` problemático del `break`:

```js
function p(max) {
  var fibonacci = [0,1];
  var q = 2;

  while (q < max && max > fibonacci[q - 1]) {
    fibonacci[q] = fibonacci[q - 1] + fibonacci[q - 2];
    q++;
  }
  
  return fibonacci;
}

console.log(p(89));
```